# Detecting Windows Tablet (touch windows devices) with Jquery

Tags: jquery, touch, device

My site run a script which is only useful with the mouse, and which have to be disable on touch screen because it don't work with them.

So to solve it i use this :

```
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

var isTouchDevice = Modernizr.touch || 
(deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/) ||
deviceAgent.match(/(android)/)  || 
deviceAgent.match(/(iemobile)/) || 
deviceAgent.match(/iphone/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/ipad/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/ipod/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/blackberry/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/bada/i));

if (!isTouchDevice) {
//my fonction
        }
```

But this code doesn't detect other touch devices mainly like windows tablets (i have one), and i would like to detect with deviceAgent or anything else the other touch devices, or all touch devices if it's possible.

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.. I have tested on ios safari, osx safari, windows IE, windows Chrome, windows Firefox, android.

```
var isTouchDevice    = 'ontouchstart' in window || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints>0);
```

Basically, we let the browser determine if there is a touch device and then look for the browser specific implementations of touch events.

Internet explorer 9/10/11

```
navigator.msMaxTouchPoints
```

All others:

```
'ontouchstart' in window
```

Comment: This is great.  Unfortunately, with the rise of Surface-style tablet/laptops, what we really need is "doesn't have a physical keyboard or touchpad". A Surface is touchscreen but is often used as a laptop, which adds a complication to usage of touchscreen detection.