# how to detect if user is using windows tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablet

my code isn't function well on windows tablet. I'm using slick-slider plug-in. and it should be deactivated if user are using touch devices.
I've inspected my site on windows tablet and instead of having "touch" class i have "no-touch" 
here is my code

```
if( $('.no-touch').length ) {
    new Slider({
        element: '.theme-slider',
        slide: 'div',
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        arrows: true,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
    });
  }
});
```

how can i detect if my site is opend with windows-tablet

Comment: Maybe you can try to see what user agent is used http://stackoverflow.com/a/14226881/5027172

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you :

```
var isTouchDevice    = 'ontouchstart' in window || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints>0);
```

From:

[Detecting Windows Tablet (touch windows devices) with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860930/detecting-windows-tablet-touch-windows-devices-with-jquery)

Comment: How about a laptop with touch screen?

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you can use navigator object:

```
var isms = navigator.platform; // win32 on mysystem
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not any straightforward API call to detect if a Windows is PC or Tablet.
Microsoft Surface Pro can be a tablet when you have it in your hand, and it can be a laptop when you connect it to your mouse and put in on table.

If you use a windows with mouse, then it is a PC! If you use a Windows without mouse, then it is a tablet.

There is no function to detect if user have mouse connected or not, but here is workaround:

```
var Mousefound = false;

function MouseActivity(e) {

  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', MouseActivity, false);
  Mousefound = true;

  // enable your slick-slider plugin

}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', MouseActivity, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code returns true on Surface, Edge browser

```
if (window.navigator.pointerEnabled && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1) {
    ...your function goes here...
}
```

you should use maxTouchPoints > 1, because chrome returns "1" on a desktop. However, browsers on touch devices returns 10

Comment: is this still true? is there any way to distinguish between tablets and laptops/desktops?

Comment: it only seems to return `1` if `mobile` view in dev console is activated?